# jquery javascript resize jitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I have some simple javascript that I'm using to auto-adjust the width of elements on pages and to vertically center the text on these pages.

My script works, but in IE9 and a little in Safari there is a distinct moment where the elements are not resized and they jump across the page. It's just a momentary flash, but it bugs me as I'm generally not a "good enough" kind of person.  Here is my own script:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var containerwidth = $("#main_content").css("width");
var picwidth = $(".picture").css("width");

$(".picture").parent().css("width", picwidth);
var correctwidth = parseInt(containerwidth) - parseInt(picwidth);

$(".main-text").css("width",correctwidth-25);

if( $(".margins").css("width") ) {
    $(".title").css("width", parseInt($(".width-set").css("width"))+10);
} else {
    $(".title").css("width", parseInt($(".title").parent().css("width"))-10);
}

var container_height = $(".main-text").height();
var text_height = $(".vert-align").height();
var offset = (container_height - text_height) / 2;

$(".vert-align").css("margin-top", offset);
[...] 
});
```

I realize the use of explicit offsets and whatnot is hackish, but I'm in a hurry and will correct it later.  And yes, I am using jQuery.

This is stored in a file, and I've tried both calling it in the head, and also directly after the elements it affects, but the result is the same.  Is this jitter just a fact of life for using element manipulation with javascript, or is there some solution I've missed on the forums?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the reason is because you are calling this in the `$(document).ready()`, which runs **after** the DOM is loaded (i.e. your elements are already displayed).

If you absolutely have to resize elements after they've loaded, the only thing I can think of that might help is having an overlay that covers the entire window, maybe something like:

```
#overlay{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 9001;
}
```

And then hiding the overlay via `$("#overlay").hide()` after the resizing in your `$(document).ready()` function. I haven't tested this so I don't know if it works. You might have to add a short `setTimeOut` as well.

To be honest, though, this solution feels very dirty. Hopefully someone else can think of something more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

@ZDYN is correct. The "flicker" happens when the page is displayed but the jQuery code has not been executed.

You can try to set in the css your elements to "visibility: hidden" so they will have their dimensions for the calculations, then change the visibility to "visible" after the resizing.